# Navigation animation not working on Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Default Xamarin forms navigation page animation is not working when using master details page

I am setting the master page from App.Xaml.cs

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MasterDetailPOS() { });
```

When I am navigating a page from another page,the second parameter is for animate.

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1(),true)
```

page navigation animation not working.

When I am not using master detail page then this animation working fine.

so how to solve this?

Comment: Did you try to use `await`?

Comment: yes I always use await for rapidly click buttons,but still animation not working.

Comment: Do you have any default Custom Renderer for NavigationPage?

Comment: No I am not using any navigation page renderer,Is it not working for master details page?

Comment: Are you sure you are creating `MasterDetailPage` the correct way?

Comment: Could you please share your code through Github so we can take a look at what's wrong?

Comment: @Sameer Its a live project.

Comment: @G.Hakim I have implemented master details page correct way.

Comment: @Vidhya You can test it on the Master-Detail template project. The animation works fine on my side using that template.

Comment: @Land Lu can you give me the url of this project?

Comment: @Vidhya Create a new forms project. Choose Master-Detail template for your app.

Comment: @Land Lu I download it from xamarin samples,but I noticed that animation still not working on this sample.

Comment: @Vidhya Which device are you using? It works both on real device and emulators on my side.

Comment: I am using my Phone,not emulator and my device OS is Oreo 8.1

Comment: @Vidhya Please test it on another device if possible. If the issue persists you can try to open a support ticket here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection?sapId=211dd84f-3474-c3c5-79bf-66db630c92a6. Upload your device log to help us analyze your issue.

Comment: @Land Lu do you solve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56801450/xamarin-forms-android-app-taking-12-seconds-to-startup?noredirect=1#comment100157308_56801450

Comment: @Vidhya No, I haven't encountered it before. It depends on your own code. We don't know how you implement the sqlite connection.