# Xamarin Forms android app taking 12 seconds to startup

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My Xamarin forms android application taking 12 seconds to startup,How to reduce it and start within 2-3 seconds?

Inside My App.Xaml.Cs File I am creating sqlite connection.This connection takes 4 second to create connection.

```
SQLiteConnection con = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnectionWithCreateDatabase();
```

Master Details page loading takes 1.5 seconds

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MasterDetailPOS() { });
```

after loading all of this things,also taking 5 seconds then splash screen goes out.

so how to speed up these things?

Comment: I tested many devices,Sumsung Galaxy J7,Redmi 7 Pro and OS is Oreo and Pie

Comment: @SushilHangover do you have any solution for that?

Answer (score 5):

The painful truth is that you will never be able to optimize it to the level that it starts in 2-3 seconds with Xamarin.Forms, at least within the current implementation.
You can find some of the tips how to speed it up:

- If you don't need database immediately, I would suggest to Lazy Load it after finishing all the necessary stuff
- Enable XAML Compilation
- Optimize the assets you are using (for different screens, [check for Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)) and enable `<AndroidExplicitCrunch>true</AndroidExplicitCrunch>`
- Enable Ahead of Time Compilation (AOT)